Visual Studio 2022 and Powershell Extension Intellisense issue
I have the "PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio 2022" that randomly causes the following error and 15 to 20 second delay while it resolves itself. This occurs when Intellisense is used and I type a $ or - .
Is there a fix for this? Or a different extension that works seemlessly?

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.6.4 VisualStudio.17.Release/17.6.4+33815.320 Microsoft .NET
Framework Version 4.8.04084
Installed Version: Community
ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0 This package contains services used
by Data Lake tools
ASA Service Provider   1.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools   17.6.326.62524 ASP.NET and Web Tools
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.6.326.62524 Azure App Service
Tools v3.0.0
Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0 Microsoft Azure
Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.6.326.62524 Azure Functions
and Web Jobs Tools
Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0 Microsoft
Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio
C# Tools   4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a C#
components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
InstallShield 2022 Editor    InstallShield. For more information visit
the Revenera website at http://www.Revenera.com. For customer
support visit http://support.InstallShield.com. Copyright © 2022
Flexera Software LLC. All Rights Reserved.
Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0 Language
service for Hive query
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics
Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9 Support for Azure Cloud
Services projects
Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
NuGet Package Manager   6.6.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
PowerShell Pro Tools for Visual Studio   1.0 A set of tools for
developing and debugging PowerShell scripts and modules in Visual
Studio.
Razor (ASP.NET Core)
17.6.0.2327201+a6a61fdfa748eaa65aab53dab583276e26af4a3e Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.
SQL Server Data Tools   17.6.13.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0 Hosting json editor into a tool window
TypeScript Tools   17.0.20329.2001 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft
Visual Studio
Visual Basic Tools
4.6.0-3.23259.8+c3cc1d0ceeab1a65da0217e403851a1e8a30086a Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
Visual F# Tools
17.6.0-beta.23174.5+0207bea1afae48d9351ac26fb51afc8260de0a97 Microsoft Visual F# Tools
Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2 AI-assisted development for Visual
Studio.


